# React Javascript comparison in return statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a webapp in react js and following this tutorials: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PKwu15ldZ7k&t=2002s can someone explain this piece of code to me.

```
return currentUser ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" />;
```

I understand that if currentUser is null then it redirects to login. Is there a way to make it return a different page if not null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code `return currentUser ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" />;` is called a ternary operator. In other words, if currentUser is true then return the Outlet component otherwise return the Navigate component. It is a shortened way to write an if/else statement.

Here is more on ternary operators:
[MDN Web Docs: ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

If you want it to redirect to a different url when it returns the Navigate component then you simply changed the `/login` to whatever url you want to load on null `/someOtherURL`

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a one-liner if statement. It reads:

```js
if (currentUser) { // If currentUser is different than undefined/null/false
  return <Outlet />
} else {
  return <Navigate to="/login" />
}
```

As this point, you can choose to return anything you want in either case. You could redirect to any page you have, you could return any other components, etc.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense.